# Intermittent error message in Skype for Business

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013, lync-2013, skype-for-business

I am getting an intermittent error message when running Skype for Business and Outlook at the same time.

The diaglogue is titled "Microsoft Outlook" and the content is "We're sorry, but Microsoft Office has run into an error that is preventing it from working correcly. Microsoft office will need to be closed as a result. Would you like us to repair now?"
Three options are: Repair now, help and close.

I have run a repair on Skype and also a repair on Microsoft office. I removed the Lync component device from Microsoft Office in case there is a conflict with the newer version (Skype for Business 2016).

I have followed the advice in the link below but still the same problem:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/installed-skype-for-business-now-get-an-outlook/9462d75a-bc5d-48b3-9342-68e7663f66f0?page=1&auth=1

This event appears in the event viewer around the same time:

> `Activation context generation failed for "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft office\root\Office16\lync.exe.Manifest". Error in manifest or policy file "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft office\root\Office16\UccApi.DLL" on line 1. Component identity found in manifest does not match the identity of the component requested. Reference is UccApi,processorArchitecture="AMD64",type="win32",version="16.0.0.0". Definition is UccApi,processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32",version="16.0.0.0".
>   Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.`

This is event 35 source SideBySide in the application log.

Comment: Just to confirm, you have disabled the Skype plugin in Outlook?

Comment: Hi Burgi, I do not have a skype pluggin in Outlook.

Comment: According to this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3077028) that error is irrelevant.

Comment: It must be irrelevant as I have been getting that error event prior to the Microsoft Outlook repair dialogue box appearing :) This started happening when my account was migrated from an exchange account to an office 365 mailbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around this for now, I have uninstalled Skype for Business 2016. Re-enabled the Lync component in Office 2013 and installed the skype for business update kb2889923.